# javascript selector not returning all elements with matching class

Tags: javascript

I am using datatables to display table data. this table has an action column to remove record. I am trying the achieve the delete action by adding the event listener to the specific class. When i am trying to get the elements by the class name it is returning only first page elements of the datatable event though we have 5 pages. Can you help me in this regard.

```
    var lastName = document.querySelectorAll('.lastname');
    console.log(lastName);
```

i need the solution in plain javascript.

```
<table id="example" class="display nowrap" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>First name</th>
                <th>Last name</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger</td>
                <td>Nixon</td>               
                <td><button class="btn btn-primary lastname" name="delete"></td>
            </tr>
       </table>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('#example').DataTable( 

            );
            var lastName = document.querySelectorAll('.lastname');
                      console.log(lastName);// i am expecting this should return all elements with class **lastname**.
            });
</script>
```

I have only included one row. assume we have 50 rows.

Comment: What do you mean by "5 pages"?

Comment: Each page isn't probably in the DOM at creation, ie only in DOM when changing to a specific page. You probably need to use [event delegation](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate)

Comment: means i have 50 records. each page in datatable is set to display 10 records/rows

Comment: i am applying datatable on already loaded static table data

Comment: Can you reproduce at stacksnippets? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Just because the datatable loaded the data doesn't mean there is a corresponding element within the `document` yet. Otherwise your query would have picked it up

Comment: Updated code snippet.

Answer (score -2):

you can include the `element` like `div`

try this.

```
var lastName = document.querySelectorAll('div.lastname');
console.log(lastName);
```

you can read this [Documentation](https://developer.rackspace.com/blog/using-querySelector-on-elements/) for better information.

Comment: So, basically, the OP should only target the `<div>` elements with a class of `lastname`, instead of just *any* element with a class of `lastname`?

Comment: which would result in only ever the SAME number or LESS results, never more